# Add third dimension to a 2-dimensional numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

I have an array which contains 50 time series. Each time series has 50 values.
The shape of my array is therefore:

```
print(arr.shape) = (50,50)
```

I want to extract the 50 time series and I want to assign a year to each of them:

```
years = list(range(1900,1950))
print(len(years)) = 50
```

The order should be maintained. `years[0]` should correspond with `arr[0,:]` (this is the first time series).

I am glad for any help!

Edit: This is the small example

```
import random

years = list(range(1900,1904))
values = random.sample(range(10, 30), 16) 
arr = np.reshape(values, (4, 4))
```

Comment: Can you give an explicit small example of input/output? 5x4 is enough

Comment: I have added an example!

Comment: Can you add an example of the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have the following data:

```py
import numpy as np

data = np.random.randint(low=1, high=9, size=(5, 4))
years = np.arange(1900, 1905)
```

You can use [`np.concatenate`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html):

```py
>>> arr = np.concatenate([years[:, None], data], axis=1)
>>> arr

array([[1900,    5,    8,    1,    2],
       [1901,    3,    3,    1,    5],
       [1902,    7,    4,    7,    5],
       [1903,    1,    6,    6,    4],
       [1904,    4,    5,    3,    8]])
```

or maybe use a [`pandas.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html):

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data)
>>> df = df.assign(year=years)
>>> df = df.set_index("year")
>>> df

      0  1  2  3
year
1900  3  2  8  1
1901  5  8  5  2
1902  3  5  4  3
1903  6  2  7  6
1904  8  8  4  6
```

Comment: Thank you! pandas.DataFrame is a good solution!